# I get an error when trying to build android releases for my KorGe app with Gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, korge

I'm working on a rather simple game with Kotlin using KorGe. It works just fine on the JVM, but when I try to run an androidDebug/release it throws the following error:

Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlinJvm'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':compileTestKotlinJvm'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':jvmTestCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.6.10.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Unable to find a variant of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.6.10 providing the requested capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-framework-junit:
> - Variant compile provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.6.10
> - Variant runtime provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.6.10
> - Variant platform-compile provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-derived-platform:1.6.10
> - Variant platform-runtime provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-derived-platform:1.6.10
> - Variant enforced-platform-compile provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-derived-enforced-platform:1.6.10
> - Variant enforced-platform-runtime provides org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-derived-enforced-platform:1.6.10

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I tried changing Kotlin version, SDK version, Gradle version...Nothin works!
Can someone help please ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3524 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45113 
Please create new request with a sample project via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KT